# "Трехсторонний" - как правильно пишется?

Tags: орфография

Понятно, что можно написать это одним словом, как в заголовке - "трехсторонний", как, например, Трехсторонняя Комиссия. Но можно ли это слово записать как-то, используя цифру? И, если да, то как? "3-х сторонний"? Или "3-сторонний"? Или "3-хсторонний" (как это совсем дико, по-моему).
Просто, если "трехсторонний" - это еще короткое слово, то какой-нибудь "шестидесятитрехсторонний" - это уже перебор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование словесно-цифровой записи  зависит от стиля текста: трехсторонние переговоры и 3-сторонний металлический напольный стенд.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Цифровая или словесно-цифровая форма в художественных (и близких к ним)  текстах должна быть обоснована и  допускается только в определенных случаях, например:
а) Когда требуется стилизовать внешний вид записки, письма, надписи: «Привет 5-й окружной конференции...»; 
б) Когда требуется назвать номер газеты, журнала, воинской части при некоторых условиях: билет 2-го займа, дивизия в составе 9-го мотополка.

2)  Словесно-цифровая форма используется в нехудожественных текстах в следующем виде:  число в цифровой форме и присоединяемое дефисом существительное или прилагательное), например: 150-летие, 20-километровый переход, 25-процентный раствор.

Неверно: 150-тилетие, 20-тикилометровый переход и т. п., т. е. с присоединением ко второй части слова окончания числительного.

http://img.artlebedev.ru/everything/izdal/spravochnik-izdatelya-i-avtora/Milchin-Numbers.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Если писать цифрами, то правильно: 3-сторонний ( предпочтительно: трехсторонний).

Если в составе сложных существительных и прилагательных есть числительное, то его можно записать в словесной форме (прописью) или в словесно-цифровой форме (цифрой и присоединяемым дефисом существительным или прилагательным). При использовании словесно-цифровой формы записи буквенные наращения после числительных не пишутся.
Ср.: 2-х симочный, 2-ухсимочный, 2 симочный (неверно); двухсимочный, 2-симочный (верно).

Подробнее здесь: [Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=435.Am3zrusQwRSafIPz7ODsDtbQfpCIZpIY4DQvTVzOYcHZuuLR0sWhMkQ4FYctmiTJ-c6aKXMDoGcEVYSXV4Q60kWf5chnm8FoNDJl486047hNhFxxIdMrPf6eDWdG-MClSujaMUMIjc-cpbELC9jfMwAgm_0OvV1NvWeaZFNZXyufPWRYIO3oi4T8kJ3VK13K.ad3c0cc985480d4ae5f7ddf45e7c065c364659f4&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsMCv5TMMN9UQmOZZ0YK44d_VVrnwO4aZqy0mc0k5ZDrHnyIKhfVPRLP9bx0gH-LHHQlvY47YXi8mqoRRpToBEctH3-l7FCTBXZ_aGQe_A3by7QAvEmO20nS12KLNZcFg0Z10HbZOcEHFpOdq4Gxc8oLegRon9EHpadaWiOe5LFU3NBr0qDQMxzjlbuIHg6d2rX808CHs9RfVuJ4t1Aum7p&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBEZktJbU8ybXhCM3hINFFfRkxMVjRNX0ZvcjBub2prUzk5ZmpYcU4yNkw2X0ZTdjNXMDQ5UmZ5bmZkdmx1a2xpSVoxLTVNNDF1UWpqcGdHT1NLR2lHcjJVckdfaXNVTjVsRXhBLXdyUDU0WEp5ZVFzM3c2aDZR&b64e=2&sign=530e79b6b6055ae1909f6473198a2f79&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1409645287992&mc=4.600285406116395)